# Display a checkmark for any value

Tags: excel, vba

Using the cell format Excel allows any value to be displayed as any predetermined character. For many years I have used this feature to display a checkmark but now the code below is giving me a headache.

```
        With Rng
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
            .NumberFormat = """" & ChrW(252) & """"
            With .Font
                .Name = "Wingdings"
                .Bold = True
            End With
        End With
```

Everything is in the same workbook:
There is an account, a journal of sorts. My code filters out entries for one subject and writes the result to a dedicated sheet. The account has a column with checkmarks of this type and they are copied correctly to the tab with the filtered data. From the filtered extract my code copies items into a third tab where the info is displayed in context. Data, values only, are transferred via an array. As a result of this method the destination tab receives and displays the cell values. The above code intends to format the affected cells to show a checkmark.

Everything works fine except that the font doesn't appear to be applied. The formatted cells do show *Wingdings* as applied font. The value is present and suppressed but instead of a checkmark it displays nothing.

The cell format is set correctly. Since it was present in the workbook before it's noteworthy that no new format was added. (The use of ChrW() is a legacy from a problem in forgotten years past. Chr() produces the same result in the circumstance.) I tried to set the font before or after the NumberFormat.

I found that my present version of Excel (365) doesn't seem to have a checkmark in its Wingdings. Surprise because it's there in the same workbook but I didn't find it in `Symbols`. Instead I found Chr(80) in Wingsdings2. Applied with the same code the cells display "P", with *Wingsdings2* shown as applied font.

Of course I checked the formatting of similar cells in the account and the filtered copy minutely and discovered no difference. I also tried to format the final cells again, using the same settings, but they stubbornly look at me with a blank stare.

As a coup de grace I applied the same code above to the ActiveCell on a blank sheet in the same workbook and it worked beautifully, Bold and all. So, what might be different on the worksheet on which it doesn't work? **Actually, that is my question here**.

Rows are inserted one by one, filled cell by cell, and a different format applied to each before the value is written. But stepping through the code with F8 produced no revelations. I also tried to enable ScreenUpdating (normally turned off while the code runs) but no different result. So, **why isn't the specified font applied correctly**?

The cells do have two peculiarities. One is that they are the last ones in the row. The other is that all other cells in the row are merged. This leads to a `Merge` command being applied to the single cell. To show the measure of my desperation I added `If Rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then Rng.Merge`. Of course, it made no difference.

Comment: It looks like a corrupt workbook or bug in Excel version resulting in wrong font being rendered. Instead of relying on a specyfing font you could use Unicode checkmark symbol `ChrW(10003)`.

Comment: @BrakNicku That works. Please put it into answer and I shall select it. Expanding upon your idea that the workbook might be corrupt, is that compatible with the same code working elsewhere? And if so, do you know of a way to perhaps repair it before the fault crops up elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, the idea is based on your description of the code working perfectly fine in different workbook. You also wrote that Chr(80) displays as `P`, so it seems that Excel uses some different font than Windings2. The only way of repairing workbook I know is copying all the required data/code to the new workbook.

Comment: Not quite. The code works perfectly fine **in the same workbook**. I even successfully tested it on the same worksheet. Any corruption must be limited to those cells. Prior to creating the rows any previous entries are deleted using `Unmerge` and then `ClearContents`. Then borders and fill is removed, in that sequence. This is followed by merging again, then setting formats and values. New borders and fill follows but by that time the error has already occurred. Somehow I can't imagine the kind of corruption that matches what I see.